# onProgress() called directly from 0% to 100%

Tags: javascript, image-uploading, filestack

I am using filestack `client` to upload images to `S3 bucket`. I want to show progress bar while uploading. When I upload any image of almost more than **1MB** the progress bar progresses in desired way, means, progress bar moves from 0% to 100% very smoothly.

But when I try to upload any small file(image) of like *some KBs* the progress bar jumps directly from 0% to 100% in zero time.

In upload options I tried smallest value of **1 Milli Second** for property `progressInterval` but not luck.

Here is my code:

```
    let uploadOptions = {
        progressInterval: 1,
        onProgress: (e) => {
            $('.thumbnail-container .thumbnail .progress-container .progress').css('width', e.totalPercent+'%');
            $('.thumbnail-container .thumbnail .progress-container p.percentage').html(e.totalPercent+'%');
        },
    }

    let storeOptions = {
        "access": "public",
        "path": temp_path+'/'+file.name+'.'+fextension
    }

    client.upload(file, uploadOptions, storeOptions)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

I want progress bar to move smoothly, from 0 to 100 in a linear way.

Comment: Probably your file can be sent in just one packet

The MTU (maximum transfer unit) for Ethernet, for example, is 1500 bytes.

https://www.lifewire.com/definition-of-mtu-817948

Comment: Not sure, because it take almost 1 or 2 seconds to jump from 0 to 100. Means, as soon as I press upload button, the progress bar appears with zero percent. After almost 2 seconds it jumps to 100 percent. What I want is, in those 2 seconds progress bar should move linearly from 0 to 100.

Comment: Can you try slow down your network? Chrome-based browsers have a network-debugging tab, you can switch the online to slow 3G there. And also try console.log-ing the state every time it updates